# Using javascript cant properly load Label BackgroundImage

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This is really simple.
I am using Asp.net Language and i want to create a label using Javascript. Everything i configure on the label is correct unless its image and i dont understand why, since the javascript doesnt recognize any kind of error on the code.
I will post the code here:

```
        var newlabel = document.createElement("label");
        contador=contador+1;//has no meaning here
        newlabel.setAttribute("id", "box" + someVar);
        newlabel.style.backgroundImage='url(Styles/PostitYellow.png)'; //doesnt load this image
        newlabel.setAttribute("Style","-moz-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;");
        newlabel.setAttribute("onmousedown", "coordenadas(event,this.id)");
        newlabel.innerHTML = document.getElementById("MainContent_box").value;;
        document.getElementById("MainContent_revenuestreams").appendChild(newlabel);
```

I searched and this is the right way to load an image, so please tell me what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting style set by this line

```
newlabel.style.backgroundImage='url(Styles/PostitYellow.png)';
```

with this line

```
newlabel.setAttribute("Style","-moz-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;");
```

swap them and it should work. Or better yet, combine all your style definitions in a single `newlabel.setAttribute("Style" ...` statement.

Or better, better yet - define your styles in a CSS class and simple assign that class to the label.

Answer (score 0):

Open your browser debug panel, look at NETWORK and see if you get a 404 error on the image load. Also, an empty element with no dimensions will not show a background image - so give it some content or size it with CSS.